# string array function implementation in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, indexer

This was from my university C# - windows forms exam, im trying to resolve some old subjects, but i seem to find myself stuck in this situation. This is my code:

```
  abstract class CarFile
    {
        private string marca;
        private readonly string serie;

        public CarFile(string marca, string serie)
        {
            this.marca = marca;
            this.serie = serie;
        }

        public string GetMarca
        {
            get { return this.marca; }
            set { this.marca = value; }
        }

        public string GetSerie
        {
            get { return this.serie; }
        }

        public abstract string GetDescriere();
    }
```

Then I have to do this:
my second class called ServiceFile : CarFile, ICloneable. in this class i have an array or list of strings called RepairComands which contains the necessary repairs. 
- a private atribute called "motor" which can only take the following vallues {gas,gpl,hibrid} .
- a constructor which throws a generic exception if "serie==null"
-overrides the abrstract method getDescriere() to return the complete description of the car file

this is my code:

```
  public class MyException : System.Exception
    {
        public MyException(string mesaj) : base(mesaj) { }
    }
    class ServiceFile : CarFile, ICloneable, IComparable, IReparabil
    {
        string[] RepairComands;
        private enum motor {   motorina,     benzina,       GPL,     electric,     hibrid     };

        public ServiceFile(string serie, string marca, string[] RepairComands):base(serie,marca){
            if (serie == null)
            {
                throw new MyException("MESAJ");
            }
            this.RepairComands = RepairComands;



    }

        //not sure if this is correct
        public override string GetDescriere()
        {
            string msj = string.Format("the car {0} with serial {1} and necess. repairs {2}", this.GetMarca, this.GetSerie, this.RepairComands);
            return msj;
        }


        public object Clone()
        {
            ServiceFile clone = new ServiceFile(this.GetSerie, this.GetMarca, this.RepairComands);
            return clone;
        }

//implemented IComparable to be able to compare here 2 files by the number of repairs needed
            public int CompareTo(object obj)
            {
                ServiceFile altafisa = (ServiceFile)obj;
                if (this.RepairComands != altafisa.RepairComands)
                             return 1;
                    else return 0;
                }
//overloads ToString to return the complete file description

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.GetMarca + " "+ this.GetSerie + " " + this.RepairComands;
        }




    }
}
```

so far so good. this actually works.

**but my problem comes now:
I have to define the interface IRep which contains 2 methods : void RepairCar() and void AddRepair(string repair). 
THen ServiceFile class implements : IRep, and the function RepairCar() will be used for removing the last repair from the collection RepairComands
and the function AddRepair(string repair) will be used to add a repair in the collection RepairComands.
(For allowing the access to the private list of Repairs we should overload the index operator[] )**

Thank you so much for your help, I'm a beginnes in C# and just wanted to understand better this subject that was given in my class so i could learn

Thank you

Comment: Is this question a long-winded way of asking "How do I create and use an interface in C#" or "How do I overload the index operator"? If so, you'll find lots of simple examples on Google.

Comment: Hello, thank you for commenting. I know how to implement the interface, my problem is I don't know how to write the code for those 2 functions (repaircar and addrepair) to do what they need to do.

Comment: You should update your question to include all the relevant code you have. At the moment you've posted some code and asked questions about non-existant other code. Add placeholder functions if you know what they will look like, and we can help you to fill in their contents. The more you do for yourself, the more help you're likely to get on this site.